# Angularjs data-binding not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my code [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRDS9i?p=preview):

I am facing two problems here:

1. when drop down item for example text is clicked, the Question type section list does not go to the proper format,
2. when selected another drop down item again, the last Question type is changed as well, but actually could not be changed.

Could someone help me on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the 'proper format'?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow Hi, thanks for reply, part of the problem has been resolved. Currently, the problem is nothing changed when clicking dropdown list element

Comment: your plunker is too completed, if you can write what you want to do we can help better? I assume you want to add new question with selected type but you can change it after creation, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn´t seem to be an error in your script.
You wrote in line 147 of index.html:

```
<script src="Form Builder.js"></script>enter code here
```

But ist should be:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sdl8Y1z5KQYVLbU0nHZd?p=preview)